# Solve ODE using Trapezium Integration

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals, numerical-methods

I am trying to solve an ODE to be iterated through numerically. The ODE is the following:
$$
\frac{dX}{dt} = \frac{A(t) - X(t)}{B(t)*C(t)} -  \frac{D(t)}{C(t)}
$$
Where A,B,C,D are all dependent on time. I am solving it using what I understand to be the trapezium rule with 1 step as the timesteps are sufficiently small (0.1s)

I have come up with the following scheme to approximation to the integral:

```
X[t] = (1 + ((dt / 2) * (-1 / (B[t - 1] * C[t - 1]) - 1 / (B[t] * C[t]))) * X[t - 1]) + (dt / 2) * (
                    A[t - 1] / (B[t - 1] * C[t - 1]) + A[t] / (B[t] * C[t])) - (dt / 2) * (
                            D[t - 1] / (C[t - 1]) + D[t] / (C[t]))
```

However, the result is not what I expected. Would it be possible if someone may advise me whether I have done the right working out of the ODE? I am very new to this so I won't be surprised if it's very wrong. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: is there a special reason to solve numerically? looks like this could fit under $X'(t) + \alpha(t) X(t)  = \beta(t)$ which can be usually done analytically with the method of integrating factor

Comment: I just thought it was easier. Using an Integrating Factor am I right in saying its IF = B*C since  e^integral(1/B*C)dt = e^(ln|B| *ln|C|)

Comment: @gt6989b Sorry I am new to IF method